# Acessing MySQL database with Windows Service in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, service

I create a windows service with a timer and i want to acess mysql database. The timer works great. I configure the database connection.
[Test connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcE1Q.png)

Test connection was sucessfully.

namespace belaserra
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        string connectionString = "server=belaserra.com;user id=belaserra_user;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=belaserra_imix";
        //string connectionString2 = "Server=belaserra.com; Database=belaserra_imix;Uid=belaserra_user;Pwd=pass;";
        MySqlConnection con;

```
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteToFile("Error connecting belaserra database: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Interval = 5000; //number in miliseconds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
        Check_new_imoveis();
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Belaserra_service_logs";

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        string filepath = "C:\\Belaserra_service_logs\\ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".txt";

        if (!File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            // Create a file to write to.   
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Check_new_imoveis()
    {

        WriteToFile("DO STUFF!!!");

    }

}
```

}

The "con.Open" gives me the exception error in the .txt file: "Authentication to host 'belaserra.com' for user 'belaserra_user' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'belaserra_user'@'188.251.3.177' (using password: NO)"

I i try to connect with "connectionString2" the service starts and ends immediately.

Comment: the problem is the acess denied for user...

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code try this is worked for me:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase { 

  private Timer timer {get;private set;} = new Timer();
  string filepath = "C:\\Belaserra_service_logs";
  string ConnectionString = "server=belaserra.com;database=belaserra_imix;uid=belaserra_user;pwd=pass;";
  MySqlConnection con;
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
        con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.open();//on connection onetime
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 5000; //number in miliseconds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
        //You forget to start timer.
        timer.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        con.open();
        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now);
        Check_new_imoveis();
    }

    public void WriteToFile(string Message)
    {

        filepath = Path.Combine(filepath,"ServiceLog_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy_MM_dd")+".txt");
        File.AppendAllText(filepath);

    }

    public void Check_new_imoveis()
    {
        // TO DO : Manipulate your database here
    }

}
```

Comment: protected override void OnStop()
    {
        con.Close(); //close here
        WriteToFile("Service is stopped at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

Comment: I tried you code and the service starts and end  immediately.

Comment: I have new code and edit the answer... the problem is acess denied to user.

Answer (score -1):

You you catched any errors from your DatabaseServer?
Mysql driver is installed on you computer??

I suggest you to modify :

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        WriteToFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = **TimeStamp.FromSeconds(X)**; //number in miliseconds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This will not help OP to fix his problem.

And technically you should could something TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds, but this will do same as OP

Comment: Yep i know but im waiting for the Catched Exception (From windows events viewer).

Comment: There are not errors in compile. But the log file writes only "Service is recall at " + DateTime.Now" in every 5 seconds. I want it to write "Connection sucessfully!" too. I have the drivers installed i configure the conection in VS 2017 and make the "Test Conection" sucessfully.